# Through two given points on a circle, construct two parallel chords with a given sum.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, geometric-construction

The problem is from Kiselev's Geometry exercise 317.

> Through two given points on a circle, construct two parallel chords with a given sum.

Here is what I have tried so far:

Mark the two points by $A$ and $C$ respectively. If we have constructed such two chords and marked the two other points by $B$ and $D$, the quadrilateral $ABCD$ is an isosceles trapezoid where $AC$ is a diagonal and (without loss of generality) $AB$ and $CD$ are parallel. The midline of the bases measures half of the given sum, and it passes through the midpoint of the diagonal $AC$.

Unfortunately, I could not progress any further from here; I think I should utilize the fact that the 4 points are concyclic and $ABCD$ is an isosceles trapezoid, but I could not find usage of the fact.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is not always possible as the sum of the two chords is at least the distance of the line segment tangent to $A$ and passing through $C$. (this is a special case when one of the chords reduces to a point).

Comment: @Taxxi can you somehow manage to open [this](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/twmyp4vp) geogebra drawing for editing to play around with it? $D$ is to move, $E,F,G,H$ are the midpoints and $O'$ and $O'_1$ are translations of $O$ by $\overrightarrow{EF}$ and $\overrightarrow{GH}$. The loci of $O'$ and $O'_1$ when moving $D$ are the two smaller circles, don't exactly know how to prove it. If that helps. Thanks.

Comment: @TobyMak Thank you for your insight.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin The geogebra figure was very helpful in visualizing the motions. Unfortunately I am still stuck in the problem.

Comment: @Taxxi: Is the radius of circle ( on which 2 points are given) also given?

Comment: @Narasimham The question itself is the whole question. I think it is implicitly given by the given circle.

Comment: To me it looks like a property of intersecting congruent circles rather than any particular construction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the picture:

[image]

Let $A$ and $B$ be the two points, and $AC$ and $BD$ be the desired chords; let $AC+BD=a$. Assume first that the situation is like on the picture, i.e. $C$ and $D$ are on the same side with respect to $AB$. Consider central symmetry with respect to $S$, $\mathcal S_S$, where $S$ is the midpoint of $AB$; so $\mathcal S_S(A)=B$ and $\mathcal S_S(B)=A$. Let $\mathcal S_S(C)=C'$ and $\mathcal S_S(D)=D'$. Then $AD'=BD$ and $AD'\parallel BD$, so $A$, $D'$ and $C$ are colinear and $CD'=a$. Also $\angle BCA=\angle BD'A=:\alpha$ as these are inscribed angles over $AB$ in congruent circles. Thus $BC=BD'$.

Note that a triangle congruent to $\triangle BCD'$ can be constructed: $CD'=a$ is known, as well as $\alpha$ (inscribed angle over $AB$ in the given circle). Thus the measure of $BC$ can be constructed, so $C$ can be constructed as well. Finally, $D$ can be trivially constructed.

The case when $C$ and $D$ are on the opposite sides with respect to $AB$ is similar, just one has to consider the translation $\mathcal T_{\overrightarrow{AB}}$ rather than $\mathcal S_S$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Before accepting the answer, I wanted to check whether I have solved the other case correctly as well. When $C$ and $D$ are on the opposite sides, after the translation, I have constructed an isosceles triangle with the base $a$ and the laterals whose length is $AB$. The angle on the base of the triangle gives an angle that can be used to find the location of $C$ and $D$. Would it be a correct construction?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let Q, R be the given points. QRBA the given circle. Partition the line segment of summed length QP at A.

Draw a parallel through B and parallelly transfer AP to BR. The point R ***must*** lie on the circle because $\alpha,\beta$  are opposite supplementary angles in a cyclic quadrilateral.

Likewise transfer AQ to BS. Draw congruent circle PABS. Let the diameter of circles be $d$. The geometric construction is anti-symmetric with respect to mid-point of AB.

First I approached in the way you suggested.But partitioning into AP, AT instead of AT, AQ led me into errors.

Fwiw found the following relation by Sine Rule relevant to the construction involving a side, diagonal ( of isosceles trapezium AQRB ) and distance between given parallel lines $h$.

$$ r_1\cdot r_2= h\cdot d  $$